# Python why variable and return show difference value from print variable?

Tags: python

```
>>> pkt = sniff(count=2,filter="tcp")
>>> raw  = pkt[1].sprintf('%Padding.load%')
>>> raw
"'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"


>>> print raw
'\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\xc4|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Raw yield different output when use print

Comment: Barring escaped backslashes, I don't see a difference.

Comment: print raw uses `repr` and just using raw uses `str` function.

Comment: I mean for difference in the output not in the value itself. I thought both use in str

Comment: `repr` does not have to use `str`. It *can* if it wants to. All it is require to do is return a string representation.

Comment: See also: [Difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: @RohitJain -- I believe you have that backwards -- `print` calls `str` implicitly, not `repr`.

Comment: @NullUserException thank you for the refernce i didnt know how to coin the term , so didnt find it by google

Comment: @mgilson.. Aww. Yeah I got confused. thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is the `repr()` representation of the string, the other the printed string. The representation you can paste back into the interpreter to make the same string again.

The Python interactive prompt always uses `repr()` when echoing variables, `print` always uses the `str()` string representation.

They are otherwise the same. Try `print repr(raw)` for comparison:

```
>>> "'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"
"'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"
>>> print "'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"
'\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\xc4|\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> print repr("'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'")
"'\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00g\\xc4|\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"
```

Answer (score 1):

[`__str__` and `__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) built in methods of a class can return whatever string values they want. Some classes will simply use a str() for their repr.

```
class AClass(object):

   def __str__(self):
      return "aclass"

   def __repr__(self):
      return str(self)

class AClass2(AClass):

   def __repr__(self):
      return "<something else>"

In [2]: aclass = AC
AClass   AClass2  

In [2]: aclass = AClass()

In [3]: print aclass
aclass

In [4]: aclass
Out[4]: aclass

In [5]: aclass2 = AClass2()

In [6]: print aclass2
aclass

In [7]: aclass2
Out[7]: <something else>

In [8]: repr(aclass2)
Out[8]: '<something else>'

In [9]: repr(aclass)
Out[9]: 'aclass'
```

`repr` is simply meant to show a "label" of the class, such as when you print a list that contains a bunch of this instance...how it should look.

`str` is how to convert the instance into a proper string value to be used in operations.